# how can I get MAC-address using IP-address python

Tags: python, linux, ip, virtual-machine, mac-address

how can I get MAC-address using IP-address the following code do not working

```
packet = ARP(op=ARP.who_has,psrc="some ip",pdst = ip)
response = srp(packet)
return response[ARP].hwsrc
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get and what do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: it sending the packet but don't get answer

Answer (score 0):

if you`re using python 3

```
import uuid


def get_mac():
    mac_num = hex(uuid.getnode()).replace('0x', '').upper()
    mac = '-'.join(mac_num[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, 11, 2))
    return mac


print (get_mac())
```

and if you`re using python 2

```
import uuid


def get_mac():
    mac_num = hex(uuid.getnode()).replace('0x', '').upper()
    mac = '-'.join(mac_num[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, 11, 2))
    return mac


print get_mac()
```

Comment: The OP was asking to convert an IP to MAC address. This only gets the local MAC.